# Sequential Workflow Transaction Aborted System.TimeoutException

Tags: 2007, workflow, time-out

I have created a custom sequential workflow with VS for SharePoint 2007. When the workflow is activated 5 parallel tasks are created.

All my tasks are created as I can see in my logging but after the last tasks is created the workflow stops by the following error:

> Error in persisting workflow: System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted. ---> System.TimeoutException: Transaction Timeout -
>   -- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
>   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.CreateAbortingClone(InternalTransaction tx) 
>   at System.Transactions.DependentTransaction..ctor(IsolationLevel isoLevel, InternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean blocking) 
>   at System.Transactions.Transaction.DependentClone(DependentCloneOption cloneOption) 
>   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.SetCurrent(Transaction newCurrent) 
>   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.PushScope() 
>   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope..ctor(TransactionScopeOption scopeOption) 
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOePersistenceService.Commit(Transaction transaction, ICollection items)

---

> WinWF Internal Error, terminating workflow Id# X

---

> System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.PersistenceException: The transaction has aborted. ---> System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted. ---> System.TimeoutException: Transaction Timeout -
>   -- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
>   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.CreateAbortingClone(InternalTransaction tx) 
>   at System.Transactions.DependentTransaction..ctor(IsolationLevel isoLevel, InternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean blocking) 
>   at System.Transactions.Transaction.DependentClone(DependentCloneOption cloneOption) 
>   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.SetCurrent(Transaction newCurrent) 
>   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.PushScope() 
>   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope..ctor(TransactionScopeOption scopeOption) 
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOePersistenceService.Commit(Transaction transaction, ICollection items) 
>   at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkBatch.PendingWorkCollection.Commit(Transaction transaction) 
>   at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkBatch.Commit(Transaction transaction) 
>   at System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.WorkflowCommitWorkBatchService.CommitWorkBatch(CommitWorkBatchCallback commitWorkBatchCallback) 
>   at System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.DefaultWorkflowCommitWorkBatchService.CommitWorkBatch(CommitWorkBatchCallback commitWorkBatchCallback) 
>   at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowExecutor.CommitTransaction(Activity activityContext) 
>   at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowExecutor.Persist(Activity dynamicActivity, Boolean unlock, Boolean needsCompensation) -
>   -- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
>   at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowExecutor.Persist(Activity dynamicActivity, Boolean unlock, Boolean needsCompensation) 
>   at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowExecutor.ProtectedPersist(Boolean unlock)

When I define the same tasks sequential instead of in a parallel block the workflow is not terminated and the previous error is not thrown. Any help is welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like this problem only appears for the parallel tasks right after the workflow initiates.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why these time-outs were occuring.

The Tasks list, contain the tasks of the SharePoint workflows had an unusual amount of duplicate EventReciever attached to it. After deleting these EventReciever all the workflows increased in performance and no time-outs occured anymore.

Comment: Can you provide/show some steps how-to create parallel tasks in a Sequential workflow.